# When logging to Graylog in nestjs, logging can be done as soon as it starts, but it does not work after that

Tags: nestjs, graylog

**1. Describe your incident:**

I looked at the docker installation guide in the official documentation and am using mongo 6.0, opensearch 2.0, and graylog 5.2.

Opensearch's SSL settings are turned off.

Phenomenologically, if you start the nestjs service with npm run start:prod / dev, etc. and record the log in graylog, it will be recorded.

Afterwards, if you keep logging in graylog, logging will continue, but if you do not log for approximately 1 minute and 30 seconds, logging will not work even if you try to log later.

After restarting nestjs again, logging will occur if you try logging.

**2. Describe your environment:**

- OS Information:

Ubuntu Docker in windows,

- Package Version:

graylog5.2

- Service logs, configurations, and environment variables:

docker run --name mongo -p 27017:27017 -d mongo:6.0

docker run -d --name opensearch -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e DISABLE_SECURITY_PLUGIN=true -e "discovery.type=single-node" -e TZ=Asia/Seoul opensearchproject/opensearch:2

docker run --name graylog --link mongo --link opensearch -p 9000:9000 -p 12201:12201/tcp -p 12201:12201/udp -p 1514:1514 -p 5555:5555 -e TZ=Asia/Seoul  -v C:\Users\eno\Desktop\config:/usr/share/graylog/data/config  -d graylog/graylog:5.2

In the graylog config file, set password_secret and root_password_sha2, and root_timezone is Asia/SEOUL,

I set elasticsearch_hosts = http://opensearch:9200 and didn't touch anything else.

please help me
what i wrong?